# Mysql extract value grouped by and ordered

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.4

this is my problem, i have a table with this

```
page_name | phase_id | type | content

Home def  | 1 |  home |<some content>
Home p2   | 2 |  home |<some content>
Rules def | 1 |  rules |<some content>
Rules p2  | 2 |  rules |<some content>
Prize def | 1 |  prize |<some content>
Contact   | 1 |  contact |<some content>
```

i need query for extract unique rows  with  phase_id value (i must set in query phase_id<=2), for example

```
Home p2   | 2 | home |<other content>
Rules p2  | 2 | rules |<content>
Prize def | 1 | prize |content
Contact   | 1 | contact |content
```

any ideas for do that?

Thx all

Comment: you want  the  phase_id  to be in ascending order right like 10,9,8....1

Comment: unique rows by what ? page_name?  in your example all page_names are unique

Comment: not important the order but i need only one rows for phase_id

Comment: @DanIonescu yes phase_id  ;)

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far, then expect help from this place. We are not your personal coders.

Comment: So unique page name is identified by the characters prior to the first space and you want the max(phase id) for each of these?

Comment: @P.Salmon yes is right!

Comment: @PrajjwalSrivastav  this is what i tried

SELECT * FROM pages
where (phase_id<=2 and actived=1) 
group by type

but obtiain home with phase =1 and not with phase_id = 2 that is max phase id for home

Comment: sorry m8 i have forgot type column for extract only type o page with phase_id <= 2  i have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Here's 3 ways to do it

```
drop table if exists phases;
create table phases(page_name varchar(10),  phase_id int, content varchar(20));

insert into phases values
('Home def'  , 1 , '<some content>'),
('Home p2 '  , 2 , '<other content>'),
('Rules def' , 1 , '<content>'),
('Rules p2 ' , 2 , '<content>'),
('Prize def' , 1 , 'content'),
('Contact'   , 1 , 'content');


select  s.* from
(
select  p.*,
         substring(p.page_name,1,instr(concat(p.page_name,' '),' ') -1) UniquePage,
         if(substring(p.page_name,1,instr(concat(p.page_name,' '),' ') -1)  <> @p, @rn:=1,@rn:=@rn+1) rn,
         @p:=substring(p.page_name,1,instr(concat(p.page_name,' '),' ') -1) prevp
from   (select @rn:=0,@p:='') rn,phases p
order by substring(p.page_name,1,instr(concat(p.page_name,' '),' ') -1), p.phase_id desc
) s where s.rn = 1 
;

select s.*
from 
(
select p.*,
            (Select max(p1.phase_id) from phases p1 where substring(p1.page_name,1,instr(concat(p1.page_name,' '),' ') -1) = 
            substring(p.page_name,1,instr(concat(p.page_name,' '),' ') -1)) maxpid
from phases p
) s
where s.phase_id = s.maxpid
;


select p.*
from phases p
where p.phase_id = (Select max(p1.phase_id) from phases p1 where substring(p1.page_name,1,instr(concat(p1.page_name,' '),' ') -1) = 
            substring(p.page_name,1,instr(concat(p.page_name,' '),' ') -1))
;
```

Comment: hi Salmon thx i 'am sorry i have update my table for insert page type for group rows thx so much for your reply, can you suggest with this column improvement?